# modal close button doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have modal div that contains close button and some text. When I click button this works. But when I click close img this doesn't work. I dont understand nothing in console appears, but function doesn't work. Why?

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
});
var appereance = true;
var mod = document.getElementById("modal");

function modal() {

  if (appereance) {
    mod.style.display = "block";
    appereance = false;
  } else {
    mod.style.display = "none";
    appereance = true;
  }

}

function close() {
  mod.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#modal {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: none;
}

i {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#modal>div {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" onclick="modal()">Demo modal</a>

<div id="modal">
  <div onclick="close()">
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
  <p>Click <a href="#">close</a> adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It won't work unless you load jQuery and bootstrap.js in your code, but also you'll need each close option, x, link to share the Demo modal a href code: <a href="#" onclick="modal()">Demo modal</a>

Comment: I want this modal works in pure JS

Comment: Sorry jQuery is required: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ "Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files). Consult our bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported." -- But if you make the links all contain the onclick declaration they should all work the same as the Demo modal link.

Comment: refer this link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: Then why aren't you following those instructions?

Comment: Why has a dependency on bootstrap been added by someone other than the OP? This is a very simple fix, it doesn't need many thousands of lines of library and CSS to get working.

Comment: You don't even need to call close function (that is system name) , just use your modal function because it is toggle function

Comment: Did my answer didn't meet your expected answer?

Answer (score 4):

You must rename close function. Javascript will prevent it from firing if you use `close`. I usually add underscore in the beginning :)

```js
var appereance = true;
var mod = document.getElementById("modal");

function modal() {
  if (appereance) {
    mod.style.display = "block";
    appereance = false;
  } else {
    mod.style.display = "none";
    appereance = true;
  }
}

function _close() {
  mod.style.display = "none";
    appereance = true;
}
```

```css
#modal {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: none;
}

i {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}

#modal>div {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="modal()">Demo modal</a>

<div id="modal">
  <div >
    <i class="fa fa-close" onclick="_close()"></i>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
  <p>Click <a href="#">close</a> adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @SahilSahilov  `close()` is reserved for `window.close();`

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekPandey for answering his question :) Have a nice day. I'm glad this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

close() is already a predefined function. Please change the name of the function to something else and try again.

Here is a working [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/OV1nRSFsb7ItgpO05w1q?p=preview)

```
// Code goes here

var appereance = true;
var mod = document.getElementById("modal");

function modal() {

  if (appereance) {

    mod.style.display = "block";
    appereance = false;
  } else {
    mod.style.display = "none";
    appereance = true;
  }

}

function closeMe() {
  mod.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The listener to "close" the dialogue is on DIV that is a sibling of the link with text "close", so the event doesn't bubble to it. Move the listener to the link.

Also, the global "close" references *window.close*, and browsers will not let you close a window you didn't open, so nothing happens. Change the name of the function to say "closeDialogue".

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

var appereance = true;
var mod = document.getElementById("modal");

function modal() {
  if (appereance) {
    mod.style.display = "block";
    appereance = false;
  } else {
    mod.style.display = "none";
    appereance = true;
  }
}

function closeDialogue() {
  mod.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#modal {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: none;
}

i {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#modal>div {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="modal()">Demo modal</a>

<div id="modal">
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
  <p>Click <a href="#"  onclick="closeDialogue()">close</a> adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working after I changed a few of things here.

1. Corrected the spelling of `appearance`
2. Called it `false` by default, and used it (correctly) as a flag for the display of the dialogue box.
3. Used `x` instead of font-awesome in order to display a "closable" sign for that icon just for demoing the working of code. You may add font-awesome CSS classes to it later.

That's it! Check it yourself.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

var appearance = false;
var mod = document.getElementById("modal");

function modal() {
  if (appearance) {
    mod.style.display = "none";
    appearance = false;
  } else {
    mod.style.display = "block";
    appearance = true;
  }
}

function closeDialogue() {
  mod.style.display = "none";
  appearance = false;
}
```

```css
#modal {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: none;
}

i {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#modal>div {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="modal()">Demo modal</a>

<div id="modal">
  <div onclick="closeDialogue()">
    <i>x</i>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
  <p>Click <a href="#"  onclick="closeDialogue()">close</a> adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```